# In set theory, what does the symbol $\mathfrak b$ mean?

Tags: set-theory, notation, cardinals

In set theory, what does the symbol $\mathfrak b$ mean? Could somebody tell me something basic about $\mathfrak b$? In particulat, I want to know the relation between $\mathfrak b$
and $\mathfrak c$.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166995/in-set-theory-what-does-the-symbol-mathfrak-d-mean/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the bounding number. That's the smallest cardinality of a family $\mathcal F \subseteq \{f: \omega \to \omega \}$ such that $\mathcal F$ cannot be dominated that is, such that there is no function $g$ dominating all functions in $\mathcal F$.

A function $g$ is said to dominate $f$ if there is $n$ such that for $k > n$, $f(k) < g(k)$

Of course the set of all functions cannot be bounded hence $\mathfrak b \le \mathfrak c$.

Answer (score 4):

It’s the [bounding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram):

$$\mathfrak b=\min\{|F|:F\subseteq{}^\omega\omega\text{ and }\forall g\in{}^\omega\omega\exists f\in F(g\le^* f)\}\;,$$

where $g\le^* f$ means $\{k\in\omega:f(k)<g(k)\}$ is finite. It’s not hard to prove that $\omega_1\le\mathfrak b\le 2^\omega$. The link includes information on the relationship between $\mathfrak b$ and some other numbers between $\omega_1$ and $2^\omega$.

Comment: @Brain: could you help me to solve this question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365321/on-the-small-first-countable-regular-spaces. I believe you will give me a good answer.