# On the small first countable regular spaces

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Here are some definitions.

> **A  countably  infinite closed discrete set $A \subset  X$
>   has  property  $D$  in $X$**  provided  there exists a  discrete family 
>   of open sets $\{U_a :  a \in A\}$ such that $U_a \cap A = \{a\} $ for all $a\in  A$.
>
> **A  space  $X $ is said to have  property  $D$**  provided  that every countably  infinite closed discrete set in $X$  has  property $D$    in $X$.
>
> A space is called **pseudo-normal** if every countable closed subset has arbitrarily small closed nbhds.

It is known **each pseudonormal space has property $D$.**

It is said in the **[Handbook of set-theoretic topology](http://www.ebook3000.com/Handbook-of-Set-Theoretic-Topology_114326.html) page 155**: The following result tells that the small first countable regular spaces are pseudo-normal;

[image]

> **Question: how to see that the small first countable regular spaces are pseudo-normal from Theorem 12.2?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$When Eric says that ‘small first countable regular spaces are pseudonormal’, he’s talking about spaces $X$ such that $|X'|<\mathfrak b$, not just spaces that are themselves of cardinality less than $\mathfrak b$. Specifically, he’s referring to the fact that $\mathfrak{b}_p=\mathfrak b$. The reason that $\mathfrak{b}_p$ is defined in terms of $|X'|$ instead of $|X|$ is that if $X$ is pseudonormal, you can add any number of isolated points to $X$, and the new space will still be pseudonormal. And since regularity was mentioned in the comments, note that the proof of Theorem $12.2$ uses the regularity of $X$.

By the way, there are several confusing typos in the proof that $\mathfrak b\le\mathfrak{b}_p$. Here, with slightly different notation in places, is a corrected version.

> We prove that if $X$ is a first countable regular space with $|X'|<\mathfrak b$, then $X$ is pseudonormal. Let $F$ be a countable closed subset of $X$, and let $U$ be a nbhd of $F$; we must find a nbhd $V$ of $F$ such that $\cl V\subseteq U$. This is trivial if $F$ is finite — note the use of regularity here — so assume that $F=\{x_k:k\in\omega\}$. For each $k\in\omega$ let $\mathscr{B}_k=\{B_k(n):n\in\omega\}$ be a nbhd base at $x_k$ such that $B_k(n)\supseteq B_k(n+1)$ for each $n\in\omega$, and $\cl B_k(0)\subseteq U$.
>
> For $f\in{}^\omega\omega$ let $B(f)=\bigcup_{k\in\omega}B_k\big(f(k)\big)$; then $\{B(f):f\in{}^\omega\omega\}$ is a nbhd base for $F$ in $X$. For each $y\in X'\setminus U$ there is an $f_y\in{}^\omega\omega$ such that $y\notin\cl B(f_y)$. Now $|X'\setminus U|\le|X'|<\mathfrak b$, so $\{f_y:y\in X'\setminus U\}$ is bounded in $\langle{}^\omega\omega,\le^*\rangle$, and there is therefore a $g\in{}^\omega\omega$ such that $f_y\le^* g$ for all $y\in X'\setminus U$. $B(g)$ is a nbhd of $F$, and I claim that $\cl B(g)\subseteq U$.
>
> To see this, suppose that $y\in X'\setminus U$. Then there is an $m\in\omega$ such that $f_y(k)\le g(k)$ for all $k\ge m$, and $$\cl B(g)\subseteq\cl\left(B(f_y)\cup\bigcup_{k<m}B_k(0)\right)=\cl B(f_y)\cup\bigcup_{k<m}\cl B_k(0)\;.$$ By construction $y\notin\cl B(f_y)$ and $\bigcup_{k<m}\cl B_k(0)\subseteq U\subseteq X\setminus\{y\}$, so $y\notin\cl B(g)$. Thus, $\cl B(g)\cap(X'\setminus U)=\varnothing$. Finally, $B(g)\subseteq U$, and every point of $(X\setminus X')\setminus U$ is isolated, so $\cl B(g)\cap(X\setminus U)=\varnothing$, and $\cl B(g)\subseteq U$, as desired. $\dashv$.

Comment: @Brain: Thanks for your answer. I still have a small question: if $|X|<\mathfrak b$, since $|X'|\le |X|<\mathfrak b$, then $X$ must be pseudo-normal. Is it right?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a first countable regular space so small that $|X|<{\frak b}_p$, then $X$ is pseudo-normal by the second row of Theorem 12.2. Is this OK?

Comment: Why need the assuming that $X$ is regular?

Comment: Because you asked about a reguar space. :-) Moreover, in some chapters of the Handbook all topological spaces are considered to be regular.

Comment: I cannot agree with you: at least in this handbook, the space is not assumed regular.

Comment: In the chapter on generalized metric spaces (the unique chapter, which I read), :-) “all spaces are assumed to be regular and $T_1$, unless stated otherwise”.

Comment: Thanks. Why need $|X'|<\mathfrak b_p$ in the statement, but not $|X|< \mathfrak b_p$? Do you think about it?

Comment: I don’t know this exactly. Maybe this was done for the sake of the equality $\frak b=\frak b_p=\dots$ or the isolated points play a small role in this and them could be excluded.